# Mysql workbench quit unexpetedly

Tags: mysql-workbench

I open my workbench, and when I open any file it crashes. I had this error:

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               MySQLWorkbench [73719]
Path:                  /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/MySQLWorkbench
Identifier:            com.oracle.workbench.MySQLWorkbench
Version:               8.0.32.CE (1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2024-01-21 20:46:50.2001 +0300
OS Version:            macOS 14.2.1 (23C71)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        92BCEFAC-EC59-6EDD-E3CB-D63B64F986B7

Sleep/Wake UUID:       83E837D2-ECC7-4BC4-A035-AA85DFB4AD08

Time Awake Since Boot: 300000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       9661 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000000000e0
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000000000e0

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process:   exc handler [73719]
```

I had 8.34 version which is suitable for most new mac versions, but I dont understand what means termination reason: namespace SIGNAL, code 11 segmentation fault: 11